# Can 10pm be considered "Late evening"?

Tags: time

I'm answering a question about a text. In the text, it says:

> The train left the station at 10:00PM

and, the question I must answer is

> Did the train leave late in the evening?

I'm not sure about this. I'd say the train left early at night, but I'm not sure if 10pm can be still considered as "Late evening".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's kind of a vague question, but if someone said that the train left "late in the evening" and I later found out that it had left at "10 pm" I wouldn't think I had been lied to.

So yes, I would say that, unless there's some strange context here, 10 PM could be considered "late in the evening"